# Sorting a mongo group by query in Ruby

Tags: ruby, mongodb, group-by

I need some help sorting a mongo 'group by' query in ruby.

I have the group by part working. The query below groups records by the hour, returning results something like this:

```
{"date"=>"2013,4,2,18,0,0,0", "count"=>1.0}
{"date"=>"2013,4,9,19,0,0,0", "count"=>1.0}
{"date"=>"2013,3,13,2,0,0,0", "count"=>3.0}
```

Ideally the results would be sorted by the 'date' field.

```
data = db[collection_name].group(
"function(doc) {
var dateKey = doc.created_at.getFullYear() + ',' +
(doc.created_at.getMonth() + 1) + ',' + doc.created_at.getDate() + ',' +
doc.created_at.getHours() + ',0,0,0';
return {'date': dateKey};}", 
{"parent_id" => parent_id, "checked" => true},
{ :count => 0 },
"function(doc, y){y.count++}",
true)
```

Comment: What should the result look like?

Comment: The results will look the same only sorted by date. Like so:
{"date"=>"2013,3,13,2,0,0,0", "count"=>3.0}
{"date"=>"2013,4,2,18,0,0,0", "count"=>1.0}
{"date"=>"2013,4,9,19,0,0,0", "count"=>1.0}

Comment: is there a reason you're using group() instead of aggregation framework?

Comment: I could not get the aggregation framework to work with a group by function (keyf). The dates are UTC DateTime and I need hourly counts. I _think_ I need a function for this.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has a built-in [**sort_by**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) function for enumberables (including arrays).

```
array = [
  {"date"=>"2013,4,2,18,0,0,0", "count"=>1.0},
  {"date"=>"2013,4,9,19,0,0,0", "count"=>1.0},
  {"date"=>"2013,3,13,2,0,0,0", "count"=>3.0}
]

p array.sort_by { |item| item['date'] }

# => [
#  {"date"=>"2013,3,13,2,0,0,0", "count"=>3.0}, 
#  {"date"=>"2013,4,2,18,0,0,0", "count"=>1.0}, 
#  {"date"=>"2013,4,9,19,0,0,0", "count"=>1.0}
#]
```

**Edit**: You may also parse the time to a Time object in the block to ensure correct sorting.

```
require 'time'

array = [
  {"date"=>"2013,4,2,18,0,0,0", "count"=>1.0},
  {"date"=>"2013,4,9,19,0,0,0", "count"=>1.0},
  {"date"=>"2013,3,13,2,0,0,0", "count"=>3.0},
  {"date"=>"2013,4,13,2,0,0,0", "count"=>2.0}
]

p array.sort_by { |item| Time.parse(item['date']) }

# => [
#   {"date"=>"2013,3,13,2,0,0,0", "count"=>3.0}, 
#   {"date"=>"2013,4,2,18,0,0,0", "count"=>1.0}, 
#   {"date"=>"2013,4,9,19,0,0,0", "count"=>1.0}, 
#   {"date"=>"2013,4,13,2,0,0,0", "count"=>2.0}
# ]
```

Comment: Right - I can make this work. However the dates are sorted alphanumerically - so 2013,4,13 comes before 2013,4,2.
What I'd really like is for the query to return the results sorted.

Comment: You could parse the times.

Comment: This is a nice substitute for having the query sort the results. I can make this work.